# loop through an object within an array in ractjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

How can I go through that array in react js is to be able to show the errors when registering but it does not allow me to get the message method

```
"errors": {
        "email": [
          {
            "message": "This field is required.",
            "code": "required"
          }
        ],
        "username": [
          {
            "message": "This field is required.",
            "code": "required"
          }
        ],
        "password1": [
          {
            "message": "This field is required.",
            "code": "required"
          }
        ],
        "password2": [
          {
            "message": "This field is required.",
            "code": "required"
          }
        ]
      },
```

I tried as follows

```
console.log(errors.username[0].message);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to loop through and show the errors.
You can use for...in as shown below:
for more info: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
const errors = {
        email: [
          {
            message: "This field is required.",
            code: "required"
          }
        ],
        username: [
          {
            message: "This field is required.",
            code: "required"
          }
        ],
        password1: [
          {
            message: "This field is required.",
            code: "required"
          }
        ],
        password2: [
          {
            message: "This field is required.",
            code: "required"
          }
        ]
};

for (const type in errors) {
  console.log(`${type}: ${errors[type][0].message}`);
}
```

Comment: the OP was vague but that seems like the answer :D